# Lean 4 'unknown identifier Proof'

Tags: proof, theorem-proving, lean

I have been experiencing an issue when using Lean 4.

I ran into it while working my way through the docs, in the [Propositions and Proofs](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/propositions_and_proofs.html) section.  Under Propositions as Types, the docs introduce the `Proof` Type:

> We could then introduce, for each element `p : Prop`, another type `Proof p`, for the type of proofs of `p`.

Below, it shows a code snippet checking for the type of `Proof`, which returns `Proof : Prop → Type`:

```
#check Proof   -- Proof : Prop → Type
```

When I try running this snippet, I get the following error:

```
example.lean:3:7: error: unknown identifier 'Proof'
```

implying that lean can not find the `Proof` type.  This is my problem, how do I get Lean to recognize `Proof`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Theorem Proving in Lean 4" is still under construction (indeed lean 4 itself is still changing rapidly), so you will probably find many issues in it. In this case, however, I believe the issue is that it is speaking hypothetically about one way things *could* be set up that is not in fact the way it is done in lean.

Here's one way to make those code blocks actually compile:

```
namespace TPIL

axiom Prop' : Type
axiom And : Prop' → Prop' → Prop'
axiom Or : Prop' → Prop' → Prop'
axiom Not : Prop' → Prop'
axiom Implies : Prop' → Prop' → Prop'
axiom Proof : Prop' → Type

variable (p q r : Prop')
#check And p q                      -- Prop'
#check Or (And p q) r               -- Prop'
#check Implies (And p q) (And q p)  -- Prop'

#check Proof   -- Proof : Prop' → Type

axiom and_comm (p q : Prop') : Proof (Implies (And p q) (And q p))

variable (p q : Prop')
#check and_comm p q     -- Proof (Implies (And p q) (And q p))

axiom modus_ponens : (p q : Prop') → Proof (Implies p q) →  Proof p → Proof q

axiom implies_intro : (p q : Prop') → (Proof p → Proof q) → Proof (Implies p q)
```

You have to use `Prop'` or `«Prop»` since `Prop` is a keyword, though.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such type called `Proof`. The docs mention it as an example of how Lean could have been implemented, but go on to explain why it was not implemented like that.